# MS-Access ODBC Connection to Oracle for SQL

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Database with Access 2003.

I want to use an ODBC connection and I want to set it up so that the user doesn't need to enter a password.

One of the problems I am having though is my sql query uses INTERFACE.Products and Access sees the period and thinks I'm trying to opening a file. IE Interface.MDB, when thats a part of my sql query.

```
Option Compare Database

Function OracleConnect() As Boolean

    Dim ws As Workspace
    Dim db As Database
    Dim LConnect As String
    Dim myQuery As String
    Dim myRS As Recordset


    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    LConnect = "ODBC;DSN=Oracle;UID=user;PWD=password;"

    'Point to the current workspace
    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

    'Connect to Oracle
    Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("", False, True, LConnect)

    myQuery = "Select * from INTERFACE.Products"

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(myQuery)


    rst.Close
    db.Close


    Exit Function

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox MsgBox("Error Number:  " & Err.Number & " Message: " & Err.Description)

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you try something like:

```
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(mQuery, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSQLPassThrough)
```

This would just send the query verbatim to the Oracle database.

In the [Access documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243019.aspx) for `OpenRecordset` you'll find this note:

> *If you open a Recordset in a Microsoft Access workspace  and you don't specify a type, OpenRecordset creates a table-type Recordset.*

This may be the source of the error you're getting.

As a rule, I would suggest to always be explicit in your parameters to `OpenRecordset`: the default behaviour isn't always consistent and it can generate strange errors.

I'm not sure about your design, but one way to make things a bit easier for you may be to simply create linked tables in Access.
In that case, you would be able to write queries against your `INTERFACE.Products` Oracle table as if if were a local `Products` table.
It would also save you from having to manage the connections yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The recordset you are creating must use a query written with Access SQL.  The table must be an Access table (a table defined in the mdb). It can be a local table or linked table.  An Access table cannot have a "." (dot) in its name.  If you were to link the Oracle table INTERFACE.Products in Access it would be INTERFACE_Products (Access will replace illegal characters in the remote database table name with "_") unless you renamed it in Access.   Thus your query should be "Select * from INTERFACE_Products"

It is possible to create a recordset using Oracle SQL, but that must be created with a Pass-Through query.